Could not load type Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider
I'm getting the error Could not load type 'Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider' , and this is the error in details from Windows Event Viewer, the application uses ASP.NET 4.8, I add DLL files manually to bin folder, since the application is old and doesn't use any package manager.
web.config
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MyRedisSessionStateStore">
    <providers>
        <add name="MyRedisSessionStateStore"
        type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
        host="localhost"
        port="6379"
        ssl="false"
        accessKey=""
        />
    </providers>
</sessionState>

Event Viewer:
Event code: 3008 
Event message: Er is een configuratiefout opgetreden. 
Event time: 1-4-2024 11:38:19 
Event time (UTC): 1-4-2024 11:38:19 
Event ID: 6008a0a85a8e47918ec3eb85f1bec3fa 
Event sequence: 2 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-13-133564450990873787 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\steam2\ 
    Machine name: MININT-JPP0LTV 
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 22060 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\codelogic 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: Kan het type Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider niet laden. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\steam2\web.config line 187)
   bij System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)
   bij System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)
   bij System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
   bij System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.SecureInstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings settings)
   bij System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.InitModuleFromConfig(HttpApplication app, SessionStateSection config)
   bij System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.Init(HttpApplication app)
   bij System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   bij System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   bij System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   bij System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

Kan het type Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider niet laden.
   bij System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   bij System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)

 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:8037/ 
    Request path: / 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\codelogic 
 
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 87 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\codelogic 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    bij System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)
   bij System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)
   bij System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
   bij System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.SecureInstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings settings)
   bij System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.InitModuleFromConfig(HttpApplication app, SessionStateSection config)
   bij System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.Init(HttpApplication app)
   bij System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   bij System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   bij System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   bij System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
 
 
Custom event details: 

I'm trying to use Redis to share session state between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core, I tried to provide the correct configuration to load the correct type, but it still doesn't work.

Where is the web.config that defines the session state provider? If it is the root web.config (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config) create a bin folder under wwwroot and add your DLL there.

the web.config and the bin folder with the DLL are placed inside the application folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\steam2
